# Does $ \left(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\right)^{-1} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial f(x)}$?

Tags: derivatives

Does $$ \left(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\right)^{-1} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial f(x)}?$$

Why?

Comment: Inversion as an operator or inversion as reciprocal?

Comment: What would the partial derivative of $x$ with respect to $f$ even be?

Comment: Inversion as a reciprocal because I do not know what inversion as an operator means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to check out the [Inverse Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).
It says that if a function $f$ is differentiable at a point $(x,f(x)) = (a,b)$ then there exists "*some neighbourhood*" around this point where there must exist an invese function $f^{-1}(x)$ which is also differentiable there (around $b$) and for which the following must hold:

$$(f^{-1})'(b) = \frac{1}{f'(a)}$$

This is kind of the same thing you are asking.